# Real time communication and debugging between Matlab and Visual Studio C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, visual-studio, debugging

we would like to create communication with debugging possibilities between Matlab and C# Visual Studio. The following example illustrates our goal:

[image: Sample sequence diagram]

What we would like to do:

1. .Net calls a Matlab .m script (which is active in Matlab Editor and contains break points)
2. Inside this running .m script, Matlab calls back to the .Net application
3. .Net application returns a non static value
4. Matlab returns the result

What we have already tried:

1. We have achieved this two-way communication with deploying our Matlab script to .Net Assembly (with Matlab NE Builder). This assembly was included to the .Net application. Unfortunately debugging is not possible this way.
2. We tried to create COM Matlab object on .NET Side, in order to execute functions in Matlab. However we did not find any possible way to call the same instance of the .NET Application back from Matlab. We also tried this solution in hopes of debugging possibilites.

Any help, comments, suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why can't you "call the same instance of the .NET Application"? First of all, you have more than one instance of your .NET Application running?

Comment: Nope, only one instance is running of my .NET App. I meant I did not know how to call the same instance (.NET App) from Matlab, after it (Matlab) had been created by the .NET App. If I try to add the assembly in Matlab, I guess another instance of that exe is loaded.